# ¿Como realizar operaciones entre dos propiedades de un objeto en js?

Tags: javascript, json, array

Quiero saber como realizar operaciones entre dos propiedades de el siguiente objeto

```
 [
  {
    "name":"Juan",
    "price":"59000",
    "commission_percent":"0.15",
    "logistic_cost":"4200",
 },
 {
    "name":"Julio",
    "price":"80000",
    "commission_percent":"0.2",
    "cost":"5000",
 },
 {
    "name":"Juan",
    "price":"5000",
    "commission_percent":"0.2",
    "cost":"2500",
 }
```

La operación seria la siguiente (price * commission_percent - cost), el objeto puede ser mas grande use este solo como ejemplo.

Luego de hacer la operación que el resultado me quede almacenado en un objeto con la siguiente estructura donde el campo **total** es el resultado de la operación anterior

```
[
 {
  "name": "Juan",
  "total": 11850
 },
 {
  "name": "Julio"
  "total": 11000
 }
]
```

Lo siento si la pregunta esta mal formulada, de ante mano gracias espero que me puedan ayudar

Editando la pregunta esto es lo que he intentado

```
const res = data.reduce((p, objeto) => {
const op = objeto.price * objeto.seller_commission_percent - logistic_cost;
p[objeto.brand_name] = (p[objeto.brand_name] || 0) + (op); 
return p;
}, {});
```

Comment: Hola, podemos ayudarte, pero antes debes colocar el código que has intentado.

Comment: Estás agrupando los que tienen el mismo nombre? No entiendo como Juan da 11850.

Comment: @azeós solo fue un calculo rápido en forma de ejemplo

Comment: @the-breaker edite

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que cada uno de los datos de tu arreglo de entrada siempre presenta las tres propiedades de

- price
- comission_percent
- cost

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Recorres cada uno de los elementos del arreglo de entrada y a medida que recorres uno a uno vas agregando a un arreglo el cálculo total junto con el nombre como un nuevo objeto, finalmente retornas la respuesta.

Mira este ejemplo

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name":"Juan",
    "price":"59000",
    "commission_percent":"0.15",
    "cost":"4200",
 },
 {
    "name":"Julio",
    "price":"80000",
    "commission_percent":"0.2",
    "cost":"5000",
 },
 {
    "name":"Juan",
    "price":"5000",
    "commission_percent":"0.2",
    "cost":"2500",
 }
]

function calculateTotal(data) {
  let ans = [];

  for (const item of data) {
    ans.push({
      name: item.name,
      total: parseInt(item.price) * parseFloat(item.commission_percent) - parseInt(item.cost)
    });
  }

  return ans;
}


let result = calculateTotal(data);
console.log(result);
```

*Asumí que "logistic_cost" es en verdad "cost"*

Comment: me parece excelente pero como muestro el total por persona.. Ejemplo Juan debe mostrarme un solo total si te fijas en el objeto Juan esta dos veces, osea que el total de Juan debe ser uno solo    `[{"name: "Juan", "total": "(total_de_juan)"}, {"name: "Juan", "total": "total_julio"}]`

Comment: Es justamente lo que te propuse allí, si ejecutas el código te darás cuenta que el resultado es justo lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Con [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) recorremos el objeto y con [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) buscamos si ya existe la entrada.

```js
var original = [
  {
    "name": "Juan",
    "price": "59000",
    "commission_percent": "0.15",
    "cost": "4200",
  },
  {
    "name": "Julio",
    "price": "80000",
    "commission_percent": "0.2",
    "cost": "5000",
  },
  {
    "name": "Juan",
    "price": "5000",
    "commission_percent": "0.2",
    "cost": "2500",
  }
];

var resultado = [];

original.forEach(function(e, i) {
  // Busca si ya se creó una entrada con ese nombre
  var find = resultado.find(function(o) {
    return o.name == e.name;
  });

  var total = e.price * e.commission_percent - e.cost;

  // Si ya existía lo suma al anterior
  if (find) {
    find.total = total + find.total;
  } else {
    resultado.push({
      name: e.name,
      total: total
    });
  }
});

console.log(resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo tendrías que hacer de la siguiente forma.

```js
const OBJECT = [
  {
    name: 'Juan',
    price: '59000',
    commission_percent: '0.15',
    logistic_cost: '4200'
  },
  {
    name: 'Julio',
    price: '80000',
    commission_percent: '0.2',
    logistic_cost: '5000'
  },
  {
    name: 'Juan',
    price: '5000',
    commission_percent: '0.2',
    logistic_cost: '2500'
  }
]

const newObject = []

for (const iterator of OBJECT) {
  const resultado =
    parseInt(iterator.price) * parseFloat(iterator.commission_percent) -
    parseFloat(iterator.logistic_cost)
  newObject.push({ name: iterator.name, total: resultado })
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(newObject))
```

Usa un parseInt y un parseFloat respectivamente para los valores de price y commission_percent para de esta forma poder realizar operaciones con los valores que tienes en el objeto que son string. Después solo tendrias que agregar un nuevo objeto con el nombre del nuevo objeto en este caso `newObject` con el método push y directamente le agregaras el nuevo objeto como esta en el código.

Comment: Tus objetos son inconcistentes ya que `logistic_cost` esta solamente en el ultimo espacio de tu objeto y el resto solo son llamados `cost`, en en cuenta eso :)